# mySql Connection keeps closing

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, steambot

Hello guys I need some help my app keeps closing my connection and I can't seem to fix it "Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection." I need to handle reconnecting but I don't know how.

***This is my output (ERROR)***

```
C:\Users\qw\Desktop\bot>node bot1.js
[SERVER] The Bot has logged in!
[SERVER] Loading Prices - API prices loaded!
[SERVER] The web cookies have been set!
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (C:\Users\qw\Desktop\bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Pro
tocol.js:103:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\qw\Desktop\bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connec
tion.js:102:28)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)

C:\Users\qw\Desktop\bot>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

***MY CODE***

```
var Steam = require('steam');
var SteamUser = require('steam-user');
var TradeOfferManager = require('steam-tradeoffer-manager');
var SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');
var TOTP = require('onceler').TOTP;
var request = require('request');
var SteamCommunity = require('steamcommunity');
var community = new SteamCommunity();
var fs = require('node-fs');

// GENERAL INFORMATION  
var sitepath;
sitepath = ""; 
var sitename;
sitename = ""; 

var apik = ""; 
var admin = ''; 
var botsteamid = ''; 
var identitysecret = ''; 
var sharedsecret = ''; 
var polling_interval  = 10000;
var rsecret='';
var snipetimer=5; 

var GameTime = 120; 

var p2=false; 

var playersRequired=2; 



var details = {
    "accountName"   : "",
    "password"      : "",
    "twoFactorCode" : SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(sharedsecret)
};


var client = new SteamUser();
var manager = new TradeOfferManager({
    "steam"    : client,
    "domain"   : "localhost",
    "language" : "en"
})


var mysql = require('mysql');
var sql_host="";
var sql_user="";
var sql_password="";
var sql_database="";
```

Comment: Where is your mysql connection code ? If you are using node mysql then you should create a config variable for the connection and then set the connection something as `var mysql_config = {
  host: 'localhost',
    user: 'your user name',
    password: 'your password',
    database: 'database name to connect'
};
connection = mysql.createConnection(mysql_config);
connection.connect(function(err) {  
// do some stuff
});
`

Comment: Dude is it you here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385060/need-help-keeping-a-connection-open-when-its-closed ?